# How to pass a widestring variable from Delphi to VB as string

Tags: vb.net, delphi, dll

Delphi code

```pascal
procedure PassN1(out N1: widestring); stdcall;
begin
  N1 := 'A';
end;

exports
  PassN1;
end.
```

VB code

```vb
Private Declare Sub PassN1 Lib "C:\path.dll" Alias "PassN1" (<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> ByRef N1 As String)

...

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Dim N1 = PassN1  'Expression does not produce a value.
    Try
        TabPage3.Text = N1
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

I get "Expression does not produce a value." How can I read the variable from VB?

Comment: Your procedure has an output parameter which you correctly declared as such. So pass a string variable as the parameter instead of expecting a return value from the method which it does not have.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: How do you pass a variable to a method? `Dim s as string : PassN1(s)`?

Comment: It's the first time that I see the ":" syntax in VB. It works, thanks. If you want, post an answer properly so I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: The `:` is only so that it can be placed on one line, so that it remains valid code in a comment where we cannot have multiple lines. You do not need the `:` in the actual program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PassN1` is a procedure that does not return a value. Instead the string is returned through the `ByRef` parameter. Call `Pass1` like this:

```
Dim N1 As String
PassN1(N1)
TabPage3.Text = N1
```

I would also recommend moving away from the `Declare` keyword which is retained primarily now for compatibility reasons. Declare the function like this:

```
<DllImport("path/to/dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Stdcall)>
Private Sub PassN1(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> ByRef N1 As String)
End Sub
```